# How to find the average of last 52 weeks sales at each time by SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a CSV file with four columns: date, wholesaler, product, and sales.

I am looking for finding average of last 52 weeks sales for each Product and Wholesaler combination at each date. It means what is the average previous sales of product **A** at wholesaler **B** at time **C** in last 52 weeks.

For instance we know sales of product 'A' at wholesaler 'B' at Jan, Apr, May, Aug that are 100, 200, 300, 400 respectively. Let assume we do not have any record before Jan. So the average of previous sale of product 'A' in wholesaler 'B' at Apr is equal to 100/1, and at May is equal to (200+100)/2 and at Aug is (300+200+100)/3.

The following table shows my data:

```
date    wholesaler product  sales
12/31/2012  53929  UPE54     4
12/31/2012  13131  UPE55     1
2/23/2013   13131  UPE55  1156
4/24/2013   13131  UPE55     1
12/1/2013   83389  UPE54     9
12/17/2013  83389  UPE54     1
12/18/2013  52237  UPE54     9
12/19/2013  53929  UME24     1
12/31/2013  82204  UPE55     9
12/31/2013  11209  UME24     4
12/31/2013  52237  UPE54     1
```

Now I am using a python code that only works properly for small databases. Since my data-set has more than 25 million rows I am looking for a better way to find the solution. Thanks a million for your help!

Comment: why did you tag it with both Mysql and sql-server tags?

Comment: You want 2 solutions? One for mysql and one for microsofts sql-server? Or did those tags slip in for no reason?

Comment: Actually I am using sql server now. Maybe it's better I remove mysql! Thanks for your notice guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.

```
WITH    cte_prep
          AS (
               SELECT
                    YEAR(date) * 100 + DATEPART(WEEK, [DATE]) AS week
                ,   date
                ,   RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY product, wholesaler ORDER BY YEAR(date) * 100 + DATEPART(WEEK, [DATE]) ) AS product_wholesaler_week_rank
                ,   [wholesaler]
                ,   [product]
                ,   [sales]
                FROM
                    [meta].[dbo].[sales]
             )
    SELECT
            CW.wholesaler
        ,   CW.product
        ,   CW.week
        ,   CW.product_wholesaler_week_rank
        ,   CW.sales
        ,   AVG(BW.sales) AS avg_sales
        FROM
            cte_prep AS CW
        INNER JOIN cte_prep BW
        ON  BW.product = CW.product AND
            BW.wholesaler = CW.wholesaler AND
            CW.product_wholesaler_week_rank >= BW.product_wholesaler_week_rank
            AND BW.product_wholesaler_week_rank >= CW.product_wholesaler_week_rank - 52
        GROUP BY
            CW.wholesaler
        ,   CW.product
        ,   CW.week
        , CW.sales
        ,   CW.product_wholesaler_week_rank
        ORDER BY
            CW.wholesaler
        ,   CW.product
        ,   CW.week desc
```

[The results look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkFc1.jpg)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It looks fantastic. I am running code now and probably takes some hours to get result. But anyway you are great! Thanks.

Comment: Welcome! You could try out the code with a subset of the data first?

Comment: I just noticed you have 25 mil rows. In that case I would materialize cte_prep and put unclustered indexes on wholesaler, product and rank. Need help with this?

Comment: Welcome! Glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sum('sales')/count('sales') 
from table 
Group by year(date)
```

What you're asking for is *slightly* more involved than the answer I gave.  I gave an answer that works if you only want to group the year long periods between Jan 1 - Dec 31.  It may be the case that you want year long periods, but maybe you want them from July 1 - June 30 instead.

The way to do this is to loo for ways to group by date ranges.  Here are a handful of links you may find helpful.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59356/grouping-by-date-range-in-a-column

[SQL Group by Date Range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364654/sql-group-by-date-range)

[In SQL, how can you "group by" in ranges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232387/in-sql-how-can-you-group-by-in-ranges)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. But what about the Date? How can I calculate last 52 weeks sales at each row (date)?

Comment: Group by date.  The answer will depend on the resolution you pick.  For example, if you group by date without time, then all the 12/31/2013 entries will average out to 4.67.  So compress all the date entries to just their year with the year() function, then group on that.

Comment: Thanks again. It makes sense to me now.